# Android - How to know the long-pressed text in the TextView?

Tags: android, textview, long-press

As the title says, I am wondering how to know the long pressed text in the TextView.

```
caption.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Log.d("log", "caption clicked");
        String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
        Log.d("log", "1: " + text);
        int start = ((TextView)v).getSelectionStart();
        Log.d("log", "2: " + start);
        int end = ((TextView)v).getSelectionEnd();
        Log.d("log", "3: " + end);
        Log.d("log", "selection: " + text.substring(start, end));


        return true;
    }
});
```

Here, I get -1 for both start and end variable. Shouldn't it return the index of text I long-pressed?
Is there any other way to know the long-pressed text in the textView?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `EditText` and override its [onSelectionChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onSelectionChanged%28int,%20int%29) method.